# How to get elem_info array from WKT or JTS Geometry in Java?

Tags: java, well-known-text

I have Well Known Text (WKT) string with geometry.
Now I want to create Oracle Mapviewer SdoGeometry, which needs sdo_elem_info array as one of arguments which is an array of doubles.

How can I extract elem_info array from WKT String?
I've read that geometry into Geometry object from Vivid Solutions JTS library, but I can't find a way to get elem_info from that either.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [com.vividsolutions.jts.io.oracle.ORAWriter](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/GIS/jts/com/vividsolutions/jts/io/oracle/OraWriter.java.htm) constructor. It "*translates a JTS Geometry into an Oracle STRUCT representing an MDSYS.GEOMETRY object.*". But for this you need an OracleConnection. It's required by that constructor. Using this kind of implementation you don't have to worry how the several attributes from the SDO_GEOMETRY object are constructed.

Another approach is taken by the [gt-jdbc-oracle](http://repo.opengeo.org/org/geotools/jdbc/gt-jdbc-oracle/8-SNAPSHOT/) extension from the [GeoTools](http://geotools.org/) project: although they depended heavely on the JTS library, the ORAWriter isn't used because it needed to introduce a direct dependency on the OJDBC driver (oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection and others) classes.

I think the [Oracle Spatial Java API](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28401/toc.htm) (sdoapi.jar, sdoutl.jar) already have such facilities: read/write from/to WKT/JGeometry. But you will not be able to work with JTSGeometry..I think. This Java API has the same license as Oracle Locator.